# Repeat NUnit inconclusive tests until it either passes or fail

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a bunch of tests that rely on some buggy mechanism. I am able to detect when the test mechanism fails and fire an InconclusiveException.

What I'd like to have is a mechanism (like an attribute, ideally) that I can use to rerun every test that threw Inconclusive, until I get a pass or fail (or a reasonable amount of retries happened). I'm not fond of the basic solution "implement a loop in each test case method".

I **do not** want to run my tests again and again until they pass, I simply want to run them until they give me a conclusion.

**EDIT**: I don't want to programmatically add loops to each of my existing tests simply because it will change the code itself, forcing me to validate all methods again (heavy process). Also, it makes for heavier and less maintainable test code.

**EDIT**: The buggy mechanism I use is the testing framework itself, an existing proprietary framework I can't change. Its purpose is to map C# objects to binary data that comes from a custom PCI card, and that sometimes fail to map. Never gonna get the budget to fix that, I have to live with it.

Comment: Why are you not fond of the looping solution?  Seems like a perfectly valid approach to me.  You can limit your looping if you dont want your tests to run forever.

Comment: The "buggy mechanism" dependency cannot be fixed? Are you sure you would like to rely upon it? And is this a dependency you could replace for testing purposes? (Are you testing the dependency, or logic that simply uses it, etc.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why looping isn't a favourable option? I'd like to know what made you reach that conclusion. It might be a problem there is a solution or work-around for, which we might be able to provide more easily.

Comment: So you're saying the buggy mechanism is actually the testing framework? If that's the case, you're either using the *wrong framework* (but NUnit is pretty solid), or you are using the *framework wrong*. Shot in the dark: are you relying on the order of test methods?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Really no way to change the library, see edit :( And don't worry, I have very clean SetUp and TearDown mechanism :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you need to write NUnit add-in for yourself. Here is the long and good explanation, how you can do that: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/testing-times-ahead-extending-nunit/

Comment: Sounds like bad news, but I'm getting used to that idea. Keeping the question open for a few days, just in case.